# Iterate rasters > create bounds > truncate names

Tags: raster, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.2 ModelBuilder.

I'd like to Iterate a large number of rasters (.tifs)  and create boundary files (polygons) for each of the rasters.   I'm using ModelBuilder and running into issues trying to use Raster Domain.  Names can't start with numbers or they are too long.   I've tried truncating the inline variable %Name% using the tool "calculate value", which worked, but I don't know how to pass the result to the 'Raster Domain' tool

Comment: You would use the output of the calculate value in inline substitution to build your raster output names.